# Spawning objects outside of camera view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on some small 2D game and I can't figure this one out. Basically I want objects to spawn - but only outside the camera view. Camera is stationary and I could use hard-coded values, but I prefer to not do that.

I tried using screen width and height from Camera.main.orthographicSize and Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint, but I only managed to spawn objects everywhere including inside the camera view.

Current code (comments are random methods I am trying)

---

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject asteroidPrefab;
    public Vector2 secondsBetweenSpawnsMinMax;
    public Vector2 asteroidSizeMinMax;


    private float nextSpawnTime = 0;
    private Vector2 screenHalfSizeWorldUnits;
    private float asteroidSpawnAngleMax;
    private float screenHeight;
    private float screenWidth;

    void Start()
    {
        screenHalfSizeWorldUnits = new Vector2(Camera.main.aspect * Camera.main.orthographicSize, Camera.main.orthographicSize);

    }

    void Update()
    {
     if(Time.time > nextSpawnTime)
        {
            screenHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize + 1;
            screenWidth = Camera.main.orthographicSize * Camera.main.aspect + 1;

            float secondsBetweenSpawns = Random.Range(secondsBetweenSpawnsMinMax.x, secondsBetweenSpawnsMinMax.y);
            nextSpawnTime = Time.time + secondsBetweenSpawns;
            float asteroidSize = Random.Range(asteroidSizeMinMax.x, asteroidSizeMinMax.y);
            float asteroidSpawnAngle = Random.Range(-asteroidSpawnAngleMax, asteroidSpawnAngleMax);

            Vector3[] arrayOfZones = new Vector3[3];
            List<Vector3> listOfZones = new List<Vector3>();

            Vector3 leftSpawnZone = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.left);
            Vector3 rightSpawnZone = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.right);

            Vector3 topSpawnZone = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.up);
            Vector3 downSpawnZone = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.down);


            Vector3 spawnPosition = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1.1f, 0.5f, 0f));
            //Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2(screenWidth + Random.Range(-90,30), screenHeight + Random.Range(-60,30));
            //Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(-screenWidth, screenWidth), Random.Range(screenHeight, -screenHeight) + asteroidSize);
            GameObject newAsteroid = (GameObject)Instantiate(asteroidPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * asteroidSpawnAngle));
            newAsteroid.transform.localScale = Vector2.one * asteroidSize;
                    }   
    }
    /*

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place objects (spawning postitions) outside of your camera view and set up them as spawn points..

Example:

[image]

Comment: Any tips how to achieve that?

Comment: I've just added a picture to my answer to understand it. Everthing which is inside the white square is inside the camera view.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to kinda do it. Not the way I intended, but it works with some extra steps.

First I created a list for all directions:

```
List<Vector3> listOfZones = new List<Vector3>();
listOfZones.Add(Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.left));
listOfZones.Add(Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.right));
listOfZones.Add(Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.up));
listOfZones.Add(Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.down));
```

Then spawning:

```
Vector3 spawnPosition = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector3.left);
GameObject newAsteroid = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab, listOfZones[Random.Range(0, listOfZones.Count)], Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * asteroidSpawnAngle));
newAsteroid.transform.localScale = Vector2.one * asteroidSize;
```